# Keeping the CircleCollider2D aligned with the sprite Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D plant simulation using 2D Sprites in Unity. The plants are represented as circular sprites. What I want to do is to increase the radius of the sprite and have the CircleCollider2D follow along. Since they have different scalings I am using a procuental increase of the radius instead of an absolute increase. But the problem is that the collider radius increases faster than the sprite, even though the relation between the collider radius and the sprite radius stays the same.

Here is the code which increases the size:

```
void Grow(GameObject plant)
{
    float currentRadius = plant.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius;            //Radius of the collider 
    float scaledRadius = Mathf.Max(plant.transform.localScale.x, transform.localScale.y);       //Radius of the sprite

    float radiusIncrease = growthSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    float procIncrease = (currentRadius + radiusIncrease) / currentRadius;    //The procuental increase of the radius, need for sprite scaling
    plant.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius *= procIncrease;

    Vector3 oldLocalScale = plant.transform.localScale;
    Vector3 newLocalScale = new Vector3(oldLocalScale.x * procIncrease, oldLocalScale.y * procIncrease, oldLocalScale.z);
    plant.transform.localScale = newLocalScale;
}
```

Comment: You should use the same scaling for your collider and sprite. Btw did you post the full code? This one does not use "scaledRadius" at all, for example.

Comment: That is the full code for increasing the size of the sprite. scaledRadius was just something that I forgot to remove, since I did not need it. How can I use the same scaling for both? To make the CircleCollider2D fit the sprite I need to decrease the radius of the collider alot and increase the scaling of the sprite. In my case the sprite has scaling 100 (on both x and y axis) while the radius of the collider is set to 0.09.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the radius of the CircleCollider2D increases with the sprite, which means that I don't have to change the radius of the collider myself.